# How to list a not complete list of records in a table?

Tags: angular

Let's say there is such a table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;" ><b>Name</b></th>
      <th style="text-align: center;"><b>Value type</b></th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" ><b>Visibility </b></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="typeEvent">
    <tr *ngFor="let attribute of attributes">
      <td style="text-align: center;"> {{attribute.name}} </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{attribute.eventattribut_type}} </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"> <input type="checkbox" class="material_checkbox" [(ngModel)]='attribute.visible' name="visible"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I display those values ​​in a table that say so tied to a particular component `typeEvent`. Simply at the moment, all the records `attribute` are output to the table, despite the fact that I select the value in the component `typeEvent`.

Comment: You can create `Pipe` and put in ngFor. that will filter your attributes array based on typeEvent. `example: *ngFor="let attribute of attributes | pipeName: typeEvent"`

Comment: or you can use <ng-container *ngIf="attribute.typeEvent==..."> ng-container not create a addicional tag in the html, https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue